# WPF .NET project does not have a .csproj file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have created a WPF project in Visual Studio 2017 and it runs without any issues.

However, I noticed that many of the guides online are using a .csproj to perform several tasks. When I tried searching for my .csproj file, I couldn't find one.

Is there something wrong with my project?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The closest thing I have is my App.config files

Comment: The project file does not appear on the project's file list, it's the project itself, it must be on the folder where you have created your project (not your solution).

Comment: Check in the folder where your code resides, you should see the csproj file there

Comment: You're right! Thank you!

Comment: May I know about the Program.cs as well? I don't seem to have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the solution then click Unload Project. From there right click again and you will see 'Edit csproj'. That is an easy way to edit it in VS.

The Main() method is created automatically. If you want to provide your own you have to (tested in VS2013 and VS2017):

Right-click App.xaml in the solution explorer, select Properties
Change 'Build Action' to 'Page' (initial value is 'ApplicationDefinition')
Then just add a Main() method to App.xaml.cs. It could be like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    var application = new App();
    application.InitializeComponent();
    application.Run();
}
```